# PID of all running processes on android

Tags: android, pid

I need to get process ID's of all the running processes in android as a part of my code. which is the most efficient way of doing it?is there an API for it?

Comment: well I think first you need the root access permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You Can PID's By following code

```
RunningAppProcessInfo service[]= manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
String pid = service.pid;
```

Comment: do i need to add any APIs for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to use [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html) for the process info. You could:

1. Get all running app processes.
2. Find your app.
3. Get its PID.

Comment: not relevant *I need to get process ID's of* ***all*** *the running processes in android*